# Button with @IBAction in a segue viewcontroller?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, segue, viewcontroller

I am starting to learn iPhone development and I like the way to start with segues and different storyboard. That makes starting to develop pretty easy, but I encountered the following problem and I am not sure if this is just an XCode hiccup or if I'm doing something wrong.

The idea is the following:

Main ViewController > sequel to another ViewController > segue to another ViewController

Everything is done with simple buttons which just trigger a segue visually placed new ViewController in XCode.

On the third Controller is a button and for some reason it is not possible to create an @IBAction. Every time I try to use CTRL + Drag it's not possible to create an Outlet. But when I place a button on the first ViewController, CTRL + Drag works like magic and I can create an @IBAction.

Am I doing something wrong, missing something or is this not working when being on the third or fourth ViewController in a segue sequence?

Thanks for helping in advance.

Comment: Have you assigned view controller class to each and every view controller on Storyboard?

Comment: what is your third and fourth controller name have you assigned to that controller to story board?